# Update Elements in table without changing table order Lua

Tags: lua

I'd like to maintain the order of a table when updating table values in Lua.

Example

```
tbl = {
        messageId = 0,
        timestamp = currentTime,
        responseStatus = {
            status = "FAILED",
            errorCode = "599",
            errorMessage = "problem"
        }
    }
```

meaning `tbl.messageId = 12345` leaves the elements ordered

Comment: Well Its easy. Hash part in table has no order so it is not possible change it.

Comment: @moteus The internal structure of an implementation's table at any point in time is not relevant to your point, which is otherwise valid and addresses the question.

Answer (score 2):

Like @moteus said, your premise is incorrect: non-numeric entries in Lua tables are not sorted.  The order, in which they are defined won't, in general, be the same order as that in which they will be read (e.g., `pairs` will iterate over those entries in an arbitrary order).  Assigning a new value will not affect this in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use table.sort, there is a simple example:

```
local tbl = {
    messageId = 0,
    timestamp = currentTime,
    responseStatus = {
        status = "FAILED",
        errorCode = "599",
        errorMessage = "problem"
    }
}

function fnCompare (e1, e2)
    -- you should promise e1 and e2 is tbl struct
    -- you can check e1 and e2 first by yourself
    return e1.messageId < e2.messageId;
end

-- test
local tbAll = {}
tbl.messageId = 3;
table.insert(tbAll, tbl);
-- add a another
table.insert(tbAll, {messageId = 1});
table.sort(tbAll, fnCompare);
for k, v in ipairs(tbAll) do
    print(v.messageId); -- result: 1 3
end
```